# CasperJS - The proper way to send AJAX request and handle them

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, automation, casperjs

I am frustrated after trying to figure out why i cannot send AJAX requests using CasperJS. I've followed the official documentation, tried to figure out myself, however no luck.

My application needs to send an AJAX to the server with an array of the names of 2 images, and the results must be a string.

this is one of my attempts, I'll appreciate any help.

```js
// idx is the index number of current picture. The images without extension as they are processed on server side
function getCalcResult()
{
 return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX('http://localhost:8081', 'GET', {'img1': 'screenshot' + idx, 'img2': 'Expected_' + idx}, false));
}
```

Comment: I think I know what the issue is, but you should show a bigger example of your code to make sure. Please [edit] your question accordingly. It seems you haven't read the documentation enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with evaluate?

```
function getCalcResult()
{
  return JSON.parse( 
        casper.evaluate(function(){
          return __utils__.sendAJAX('http://localhost:8081', 'GET', {'img1': 'screenshot' + idx, 'img2': 'Expected_' + idx}, false);
        }
    );
}
```